# How to join values from hash-maps?

Tags: sql, join, clojure, hashmap, lookup

i fetched some SQL tables via JDBC and I need to do another transformation before i create a new table and insert values.

I got these two hash-maps:

Chapters:

```
(
{:chapter_uuid "b7984dde-50a1-4147-bfee-95bbd068e031", :l1_chapter_text 
120876M, :l2_chapter_text nil, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text nil} 

{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text 
120880M, :l2_chapter_text 120876M, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text 
121621M}
)
```

Translation:

```
(
{:translation_id 3258779M, :translation_text 120876M, :translation_language "cs", 
:translation_name "Vnější fasáda"} 

{:translation_id 3258780M, :translation_text 120876M, :translation_language "en", 
:translation_name "Exterior Signage"} 

{:translation_id 3258782M, :translation_text 120880M, :translation_language "cs", 
:translation_name "Čistá výloha"} 

{:translation_id 3258783M, :translation_text 121621M, :translation_language "cs", 
:translation_name "Vnější signalizace"} 

{:translation_id 3258784M, :translation_text 121621M, :translation_language "en", 
:translation_name "Pre-signalization"}
)
```

**This is what i need to get:**

*Where Chapters.lx_chapter_text = Translation.translation_text -> swap Chapters.lx_chapter_text with translation_name and insert :language value -> Make sure that every language has its own hash-map!*

```
(
{:chapter_uuid "b7984dde-50a1-4147-bfee-95bbd068e031", :l1_chapter_text 
"Vnější fasáda", :l2_chapter_text nil, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text nil 
:language "cs"}

{:chapter_uuid "b7984dde-50a1-4147-bfee-95bbd068e031", :l1_chapter_text 
"Exterior Signage", :l2_chapter_text nil, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text nil 
:language "en"}

{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text
"Čistá výloha", :l2_chapter_text "Vnější fasáda", :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text
"Vnější signalizace" :language "cs"}

{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text
120880M, :l2_chapter_text "Exterior Signage", :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text
"Pre-signalization" :language "en"}
)
```

**This is how far i´ve got:**

*but as you can see this is not right (bad nested)*

Can you tell me how to do it right? Thank you!

```
(defn test_table []
    (for [language (distinct(map #(:translation_language %) translation))]
        (for [chapter chapters]
            (for [text translation]
            (cond
            (and (= (:l1_chapter_text chapter) (:translation_text text)) (= (:translation_language text) language))
              (assoc chapter :l1_chapter_text (:translation_name text) :language (:translation_language text))
            (and (= (:l2_chapter_text chapter) (:translation_text text)) (= (:translation_language text) language))
              (assoc chapter :l2_chapter_text (:translation_name text) :language (:translation_language text))
            (and (= (:l3_chapter_text chapter) (:translation_text text)) (= (:translation_language text) language))
              (assoc chapter :l3_chapter_text (:translation_name text) :language (:translation_language text))
            (and (= (:l4_chapter_text chapter) (:translation_text text)) (= (:translation_language text) language))
              (assoc chapter :l4_chapter_text (:translation_name text) :language (:translation_language text))))))

(test-table)

->
((({:chapter_uuid "b7984dde-50a1-4147-bfee-95bbd068e031", :l1_chapter_text "Vnější fasáda", 
:l2_chapter_text nil, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text nil, :language "cs"} 
nil nil nil nil) 
({:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text 120880M, 
:l2_chapter_text "Vnější fasáda", :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text 121621M, :language "cs"} 
nil 
{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text "Čistá výloha", 
:l2_chapter_text 120876M, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text 121621M, :language "cs"} 
{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text 120880M, 
:l2_chapter_text 120876M, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text "Vnější signalizace", :language "cs"} 
nil)) 
((nil 
{:chapter_uuid "b7984dde-50a1-4147-bfee-95bbd068e031", :l1_chapter_text "Exterior Signage", 
:l2_chapter_text nil, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text nil, :language "en"} 
nil nil nil) 
(nil 
{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text 120880M, 
:l2_chapter_text "Exterior Signage", :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text 121621M, :language "en"} 
nil nil 
{:chapter_uuid "23df4f27-534b-4cdb-81ed-dbdc8b9b140c", :l1_chapter_text 120880M, 
:l2_chapter_text 120876M, :l3_chapter_text nil, :l4_chapter_text "Pre-signalization", :language "en"})))
```

Comment: How do you want to join values? according to what? if you have {:a 1} and {:a 2} what is `a` going to be?

Comment: I am sorry, I don´t understand your question.
There is :l*_chapter_text that can be assigned to :translation_text 
for every language once...

Comment: Why not join this in the db/sql right away?

Comment: I dont know how to write in in SQL :-). 
The Chapter hash-map is already result of SQL thats expand hierarchy (original table has just UUID, CHAPTER, PARENT,  TEXT fields) and i don't know how to combine that SQL with the one you propossing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do you have a list of all languages that are used in translations? If not, let's derive it from the `translations` collection:

```
(def langs (distinct (map :translation_language translations))) ;; => ("cs" "en")
```

Second, as you are going to use the `translations` collection as a lookup table, it makes sense to make a map of it. The easiest (though maybe not the most efficient) way to do it is to use the `group-by` function:

```
(def translations-map
  (group-by (juxt :translation_text :translation_language) translations))
```

Looks like what you need to do is to convert each `:l<#>_chapter_text` to the actual text, or keep the id if the translation is not available in the given language. Using the map we have created, it is almost trivial:

```
(defn translate [id lang]
  (or (:translation_name (first (get translations-map [id lang])))
      id))
```

Now, let's put it all together, taking each `chapter` and, for each language, trying to replace all ids with translations:

```
(for [chapter chapters
      lang langs]
  (-> chapter
      (assoc :language lang)
      (update :l1_chapter_text translate lang)
      (update :l2_chapter_text translate lang)
      (update :l3_chapter_text translate lang)
      (update :l4_chapter_text translate lang)))
```

This should return the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
(let [a ...
      b ...]
  (as-> [:l1_chapter_text :l2_chapter_text :l3_chapter_text :l4_chapter_text] 
        relations
        (interleave relations (repeat :translation_text))
        (apply hash-map relations)
        (mapcat #(clojure.set/join a b (into {} [%])) relations)
        (group-by (fn [a] (apply str ((juxt :chapter_uuid :l1_chapter_text :l2_chapter_text :l3_chapter_text :l4_chapter_text :translation_language) a))) relations)
        (vals relations)))
```